# Can I replace a new Field's data in Solr?

Tags: solr, indexing

Can I replace the data in the field using filter?

Let assume data.

```
<doc>
  <field name=id>1</field >
  <field name=contents>a article about specific subject</field>
</doc>
```

And I copy the contents field to category field

```
<copyField source="contents" dest="category"/>
```

Category field has a filter.

```
<field name="category" type="myType" stored="true" />

<fieldType name="myType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="myTokenizer"/> 
    <filter class="myFilter"/> 
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I want to categorize this documents which category it is, and put the result likes 'positive', 'negative' in the category field using the filter. I already implemented a object-myFilter-to categorize using LDA, and this object uses already defined topic model. 
How can I replace a origin data to the result in category field? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible as the Tokenizers would take in a Reader and tokenize and filter it.
In your case you can use a KeywordTokenizer so that the input is not tokenized and you can design a filter to check the language of the Contents to populate the Category field.

e.g. [developing-your-own-solr-filter](http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/)

You would just need to replace the current contents with the LDA result.